# Cannot run .exe (unsigned?) applications inside nanoserver

Tags: docker, exe, docker-for-windows, nano-server

I'm getting hard time finding, what security is in place inside `Docker NanoServer Container` - when I execute `.exe` file (for example .net x32 or x64 unsigned application or some other installer) inside - I get absolutely no error or execution flow message.

When I execute signed applications [For example Systinternals Nano suite](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite-Nano.zip), all of applications from the package can be executed without any issues.

Is there a way for more verbose output or some system logs inside Nanoserver for better diagnosis of this issue ?

**My Docker NanoServer Container version:**

BuildNumber: `14393`

Version: `10.0.14393`

`64-bit`

Comment: There was a good comment that would help investigate this issue on M$:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d12df17-e803-4b12-ac82-6df99eb774cc/docker-on-windows-cannot-execute-exe-files-inisde-nanoserver-container-security-policies?forum=windowscontainers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45d0055e-f062-4b67-8587-de2e53e56232/nano-server-and-net-framework?forum=NanoServer), Nano server is support only **.Net Core**, and not full .Net framework.

Also, [MS declined request](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295068-nano-server/suggestions/8106009-enable-full-net-framework-on-nano) to support full .Net versions in the Nano Server.